# Google Cloud Endpointについて、あるエンドポイントだけ限定したユーザーのみ実行できるようにしたい

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud

お世話になっております。

Google Cloud Endpointを使用し、APIを作成しているのですが、あるEndpointのみ
限定したユーザーだけが実行できるようにしたいと考えています。

例えば
コンテンツデータであればPOST, PUT, DELETEはAdminのみ。
ユーザーが作成したデータであればPOST, PUT, DELETEは作成したユーザーのみ。
等です。

皆様はどのように管理されているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adminが、Developerという意味であれば、[User Service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/) を利用して、アクセス制御を行うのが簡単です。
マスタデータの登録APIや、Cron, TQから実行するAPIは、UserService.Adminで制限をかけるようにします。

Adminが、AdminのRoleを持ったUserという意味であれば、要件に合わせて自分で実装します。
一番単純なのは、Userのデータに紐付けてAdmin Flagを入れて、プログラム側で判定を入れるとかですね。その場合、だれがAdminなのかを管理する機能を作成する必要があります。
もしUserがGoogle AppsのUserであれば、[Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/) を利用すれば、Google Groupと連携させることもできます。
admin@example.comのようなグループを作成し、そのグループに所属しているメンバーはAdminとみなすという実装になります。Google Groupと連携させるメリットは、admin@example.comのメンバーの管理はGroupの機能で行えるので、自前で管理画面を作る必要がないことです。